# Convert SQL result set to JSON

Tags: java, jackson

I have a result set coming from `SQL` and the result set is such that it might contain results of same kind as children (kind of a tree). I want to covert this tree kind of structure to a `JSON` format. I am wondering how to achieve this basically. I want to convert my `ResultSet` into a tree and then into `JSON`. My `JSON` should look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "value",
    "children":
     [
        {
            "name": "value",
            "children": 
            [
                {
                    "name": "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use `Jackson` library.

Comment: I do not understand how you want to convert `java.sql.ResultSet` to tree. SQL returns rows with some columns. My best understanding of your question is: 1. You want to convert single `java.sql.ResultSet` to `POJO` and after that convert this `POJO` to `JSON`, yes?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? With Postgres you could return the resultset directly as JSON

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ObjectMapper](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/).  Should do the trick for you I think.